# Custom HTTP header in the AppCache requests

Tags: html5-appcache

Is it possible to add a custom HTTP header to each request executed as a cache update?

i.e.
**cache.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/page1.html
/page2.html
```

I would like the requests for the `page1.html` and `page2.html` be executed with a custom HTTP header of `X-Custom-Header: foo`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

It appears the custom headers from the original request will be applied to the app cache request as well.

So when I'm accessing `page1.html` I need to set the custom header. When the app cache requests the `page2.html` it will do so with the same custom header.